# svg:marker arrowhead not always displayed

Tags: angular, svg

I am using a SVG graph component in Angular which displays nodes with links between. At the end the link has an arrowhead. This works great. However if I create two or more instances of the graph component the arrows only appear in the first graph.

If I look at the html syntax all the graphs have the arrow and path templates in place. I thought maybe this was related to that the arrows need unique id´s and when making multiple instances there are many arrow markers with the same id.

So I tried making the id´s dynamic with the help of Angular however in that case no arrow was displayed even though the id and marker-end are in place in the html. The code shows how the graph is rendered.

Any idea why the arrows are only appearing in the first instance of the graph?

```
    <ngx-graph [links]="links" [nodes]="nodes">
                <ng-template #nodeTemplate let-node>
                <svg:g class="node"></svg:g>
            </ng-template>

            <ng-template #linkTemplate let-link>
                <svg:g class="edge">
                    <svg:marker id="arrow" viewBox="0 -5 10 10" refX="8" refY="0" markerWidth="4" markerHeight="4" orient="auto">
                        <svg:path d="M0,-5L10,0L0,5" class="arrow-head" />
                    </svg:marker>  
<svg:path [attr.marker-end]="url(#arrow)">
                </svg:path>                  
                </svg:g>
            </ng-template>
    </ngx-graph>
```

Here is the code with dynamic id's , the id's are printed corretly to the dom tree but in this case none arrow heads are displayed:

```
<ng-template #linkTemplate let-link>
            <svg:g class="edge">
                <svg:marker id="{{link.id}}" viewBox="0 -5 10 10" refX="8" refY="0" markerWidth="4" markerHeight="4"
                    orient="auto">
                    <svg:path d="M0,-5L10,0L0,5" class="arrow-head" />
                </svg:marker>                   
                 <svg:path [attr.marker-end]="'url(#'+ link.id +')'">
                </svg:path>                    
            </svg:g>
        </ng-template>
```

Comment: A template with a fixed id is almost always going to be trouble. All ids must be unique in a document so you're only going to be able to create a single valid marker here.

Comment: I have used ngx-graph in one of my projects. But I can't figure out your problem this way. Can you provide a demo?

Comment: Hi @Arcteezy it´s a bit tricky to provide a demo cause my solution is quite complex. But basically I am just trying to display two <ngx-graph /> components in the same dom tree. And the problem is when I do this, the other graph doesn't display the arrow heads on the lines. Not sure if this is an error coming in svg or the ngx-graph component.

Comment: Hi @RobertLongson thanks for the suggestion, I actually tried dynamic id's, see updated code sample but without success. Assuming the problem is related to something else, any other suggestions?